# How to put pictures in ImageView with database that contains just the names of the pictures?

Tags: android, database, image

I created a database that contains a column called images. This column is a text type. In the column I entered the names of the pictures. The pictures are saved in the resource file on Android device. My question is how to put those pictures in the Image View if i have just the names of the pictures in my database?

I believe its just one row of code something like imageview.setImageResources... but i cant figure it out. Please help me.

Comment: if i write imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture_1); my listview shows me for every item the same picture.... but i want to show me different pictures

Comment: I believe you can't do `imageview.setImageRe‌​source(R.id.picture_1)` unless `picture_1` is a drawable resource. I am not entirely sure what you are asking, though. It is not possible to just save the names of the images in the database and then set them to an `ImageView`. You would need to save the URIs of the images. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried that line and it works, but every listview entity has the same picture and its static. It does like that because it doesnt use the database, just the images from resource drawable file. I want it to be dynamic. I want  instead of picture_1 insert the names from my database?

Comment: Exactly. Which is why you have to store the URIs of the images and use Glide or Picasso libs like Md Sufi Khan suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You may try like below

```
Glide.with(context).load(getImageResourceId(context, imageName)).into(imageview);

public int getImageResourceId(Context context, String imageName) {
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
}
```

Comment: Its not working :( I cant write getImageResourceId from the first row.

Comment: Hey!! I saved URI path in my database and used this line code and it works :D iv_image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(item.getImage())); Anyway thank you and @IshitaSinha a lot for help!

Comment: That means you didn't explain your problem in the question properly. You said you saved 'Image Name' instead of 'URI' path. By the way, happy to hear that your problem is solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter
{
    private Activity activity;
    int id;
    ArrayList<Item> items;
    public Adapter(Activity context, int resource, ArrayList<Item> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.activity=context;
        this.id=resource;
        this.items=objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(id, null);
        }
        Item item = items.get(position);
        TextView tv_id=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
        TextView tv_title=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        TextView tv_content=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_content);
        ImageView iv_image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);

        tv_id.setText(item.getId());
        tv_title.setText(item.getTitle());
        tv_content.setText(item.getContent());

        //everything works, just this not
        String picture_path="R.drawable."+ item.getImage();
        iv_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(picture_path));


        return convertView;
    }
}
```